# What are the best options for exchanging $10,000 into euros?

Tags: foreign-exchange

In anticipation of moving to Poland, I'm confused how best to convert, transfer and maintain money for a 1-2 years stay.  Don't want to be dependent upon credit cards.

Comment: They use PLN not EUR in Poland. Why do you want the money in EUR?

Comment: See this question for a similar problem: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/81951/20154

Comment: Firstly if you mean USD you need to say that not just $ (several other currencies use the $ symbol) and secondly the answer to this question is highly dependent on where you are to start with. If you are in the US, or Poland, or another country, you should say so.